# how to create header and footer using divs instead of table? php, html, css

Tags: php, html, css

I have this header/footer, but the problem is that the html to pdf converted I'm using doesn't support styles within tables (i.e. mpdf). I want to wrap the header and footer using divs but I'm new to all this and not sure how to do it exactly.

this is the header part

```
<table width='100%' class='print_only_wrapper'>
  <thead class='print_only_header'>
<tr>
<td align='"($centered?"center":"right")."'class='print_only_wrapper'> The header </td>
</tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>

"content goes here"
```

this is the footer part

```
 </td></tr></tbody>
  <tfoot class='print_only_footer'>
<tr>
<td align='".($centered?"center":"right")."'>   footer text    </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>"
```

Comment: Since you are new, all you got to do is, `Never use table layout`. Start with `div` and it will be easy..

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9rEh/7/)

CSS

```
    body
    {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #header
    {
        width: 100%;
        background: #333333;
        height: 70px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    #container
    {
        color: #000000;
        height: 350px; // later you can change this height;
    }
    #footer
    {
        width: 100%;
        background: #333333;
        height: 70px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        container
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

HTML

```
<div class="header">header content here</div>
<div class="content">body content here</div>
<div class="footer">footer content here</div>
```

CSS

```
.header{
  //styles
}

.content{
  //styles
}

.footer{
  //styles
}
```

Dont use tables unless you are displaying tabular data. They are not meant for layouts